# How to sent .jar app to client but they dont have to install JVM to run

Tags: java

i want to sent my app java to clients but they dont have to install JVM to run. They just click double in app and run.

How do i have to adjust my app ?
i hope everybody guide. Thank you!

Comment: there is a tool that can converts from java to .exe application.
otherwise you have to create a web application  hosted by your server

Answer (score 0):

> How do i have to adjust my app ?

It is **not possible** to run any java application without the JVM installed.

The JVM (Java Virtual Machine) is responsible for interpeting the bytes in the .class files and therefor is the connection or translater between your code and the CPU of the PC. Your CPU can not work with .class files eg. you compiled application